# yum install failing with strange output

Tags: fedora, yum, repository

I am using below command to install gcc on my laptop running fedora 17.

```
yum install gcc
```

But I am getting strange output.

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-                transaction first to finish them.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.7.0-5.fc17 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 for package: gcc-4.7.0-5.fc17.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.15-37.fc17 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.15-37.fc17 for package: glibc-devel-2.15-37.fc17.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.15-37.fc17 for package: glibc-devel-2.15-37.fc17.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers for package: glibc-devel-2.15-37.fc17.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.15-37.fc17 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.15-37.fc17 for package: glibc-devel-2.15-37.fc17.x86_64
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.15-37.fc17 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.15-37.fc17 for package: glibc-headers-2.15-37.fc17.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: glibc-headers-2.15-37.fc17.x86_64 (fedora)
       Requires: glibc = 2.15-37.fc17
       Installed: glibc-2.15-56.fc17.i686 (@updates)
           glibc = 2.15-56.fc17
       Available: glibc-2.15-37.fc17.i686 (fedora)
           glibc = 2.15-37.fc17
Error: Package: glibc-devel-2.15-37.fc17.x86_64 (fedora)
       Requires: glibc = 2.15-37.fc17
       Installed: glibc-2.15-56.fc17.i686 (@updates)
           glibc = 2.15-56.fc17
       Available: glibc-2.15-37.fc17.i686 (fedora)
           glibc = 2.15-37.fc17
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 141 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
1:NetworkManager-0.9.4.0-9.git20120521.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with 1:NetworkManager-    0.9.4.0-7.git20120403.fc17.x86_64
1:NetworkManager-glib-0.9.4.0-9.git20120521.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with     1:NetworkManager-glib-0.9.4.0-7.git20120403.fc17.x86_64
PackageKit-0.7.5-1.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with PackageKit-0.7.4-3.fc17.x86_64
PackageKit-glib-0.7.5-1.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with PackageKit-glib-0.7.4-    3.fc17.x86_64
PackageKit-yum-0.7.5-1.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with PackageKit-yum-0.7.4-3.fc17.x86_64
abrt-2.0.10-4.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with abrt-2.0.10-3.fc17.x86_64
abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.10-4.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with abrt-addon-ccpp-2.0.10-3.fc17.x86_64
abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.0.10-4.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.0.10-3.fc17.x86_64
abrt-addon-python-2.0.10-4.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with abrt-addon-python-2.0.10-3.fc17.x86_64
abrt-addon-vmcore-2.0.10-4.fc17.x86_64 is a duplicate with abrt-addon-vmcore-2.0.10-3.fc17.x86_64................
```

Currently my `/etc/yum.repos.d/` folder has only one file `fedora.repo`.

Contents of `fedora.repo`.Contents of this file looks ok to me.Is there any other location I should check ?

```
[fedora]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch
failovermethod=priority
    #baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/    $basearch/os/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-    $releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=1
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch

[fedora-debuginfo]
name=Fedora $releasever - $basearch - Debug
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/    $basearch/debug/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-debug-    $releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=0
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch

[fedora-source]
name=Fedora $releasever - Source
failovermethod=priority
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/$releasever/Everything/    source/SRPMS/
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-source-  $releasever&arch=$basearch
enabled=0
metadata_expire=7d
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-fedora-$basearch
```

Comment: easy workaround is download and install from tarball of gcc and what is the output of `yum --skip-broken`

Comment: please don't post the same question in different forum,duplicate question:http://superuser.com/questions/512009/yum-install-failing-with-strange-output

Comment: @harish.venkat What's wrong with cross posting this, I for example don't look at superuser so I would never have seen this question.

Comment: @MarkCohen see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu for explanation, its generally followed here.

Comment: @harish.venkat, please don't tell people to bypass the package manager. That only causes grief later on.

Comment: @g4ur4v Try `yum remove <affected package>` then try the update again

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the updates repo for unfathomable reasons. Add it and try again. :)

Comment: The updates repo is not kept in the same .repo file as the main repo. It does not need to be added in his case. They like to doc points here. Careful with your answers

Comment: I am being careful. The OP said "Currently my /etc/yum.repos.d/ folder has only one file fedora.repo." That directory needs fedora-updates.repo as well.

Comment: Can you add more information to your answer? How would the original poster add the updates repo? Are there references to assist?

Comment: Create a file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ named fedora-updates.repo with the content listed here: http://arunprakash.fedorapeople.org/HTTP%20Repos/fedora-updates.repo and then 'yum update'

Answer (score 0):

I would either remove the rpms `rpm -e rpm` and then re-install them, or yum update --skip-broken and then try another update. It looks like your rpmdb might have duplicate entries that have pre-requires built into the spec files that are causing you grief.

Comment: No, it is just that if you have packages for several architectures installed, they share files (documentation, part of the configuration), so they **must** be the exact same version. Somehow that got messed up here.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the current gcc rpms which are in i686 architecture .Command `rpm -e` can help you with that. I see, there is conflict happening due to multiple architecture  rpm getting installed .
So while doing a fresh installation of gcc make sure that you add the correct architecture along with package name 
 for example :

```
yum install gcc.xx.xx._x86_64
or 
yum install gcc.xx.xx._i686
```